# Extending setuptools install command, fails with pip --user-options option

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am extending a python setup.py file. Adding some extra options to decide which environment to install.

I extended the class "install" like this:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class BatchInstallCommand(install):
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('local', None, 'Local installation'),
        ('devel', None, 'Develpment installation')
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        install.initialize_options(self)
        self.local = None
        self.devel = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        install.finalize_options(self)
        assert (self.local or self.devel)

    def run(self):
        self.install_config_files()  # Install enviroment files
        install.run(self)

    def install_config_files(self):
         # function that install files depending the enviroment
         ...
```

This approach works fine using normal setup.py install and passing the optional parameter like this:

```
$ python setup install --local
```

I would like to use pip in the same way, passing the optional parameter with the pip parameter --install-option like this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade ./package --install-option="--local"
```

But it does not work at all, because pip passes "--local" option to all package dependencies and those packages don't know about this custom option. So I obtain errors like this:

```
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

  error: option --local not recognized
```

It happens when I install using the --upgrade option. If I install my package in a fresh virtual env, pip can install the package without problems.

Any suggestions?